# kannada font support in lower version of android device

Tags: android, fonts

i am developing an app where it uses Kannada.I have used db in my app where it has Kannada words but my problem is when i run that program in lower version of android device there is conjunction problem,it won't read the Kannada font correctly i have used the Typeface still it wont work. I have searched and searched but didn't find the answer. can someone help me out with this?? here is what i have done so far. I have used both tunga.ttf & baraha.ttf.But when i use baraha.ttf no Kannada fonts appear when i run the app.

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getBaseContext().getAssets(),
        "fonts/tunga.ttf");
        //to get the views

        txt_tag[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_tag1);
        txt_tag[0].setOnClickListener(this);
        txt_tag[0].setTypeface(tf);

        txt_tag[1] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_tag2);
        txt_tag[1].setOnClickListener(this);
        txt_tag[1].setTypeface(tf);

        txt_tag[2] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_tag3);
        txt_tag[2].setOnClickListener(this);
        txt_tag[2].setTypeface(tf);

        txt_tag[3] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_tag4);
        txt_tag[3].setOnClickListener(this);
        txt_tag[3].setTypeface(tf);
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of Android are you using? As I have seen, only the Samsung Galaxy Ace S5830 has font rendering support. You have to do some work around to get the fonts.
http://chetangole.com/blog/2011/08/enabling-installing-hindi-marathi-unicode-fonts-on-android-mobile/

Comment: no it depends upon the android version from 1.6 and above it wont support Kannada till the version 2.3 i guess above that it has inbuilt font support.